# How to represent a number that longer than long and print it

Tags: java, arrays, binary

I have an int array that each of its cell contains the number 0/1, the array represent a binary number.
I want to print the decimal number presentation of the array. In order to do so, I need to convert each bit in a cell with the form 2^n (n is the cell number) and summarize all the powers.
But, with large arrays the sum can exceeds the long boundaries.
I’m looking for a solution without using the class BigInteger/BigDecimal - it’s part of an assignment I got in university.

Comment: Then you will have to implement a class like `BigInteger` that uses an `int[]` to store its value. But why would you wanna do that!?!

Comment: and why not using the primitive type of `double` ?

Comment: @Agus Loss of precision. Question already says there's more than 63 bits (since it exceeds capacity of `long`), so the 53 bits of precision supported by `double` is worse.

Comment: Why don't you want to use `BigInteger`? It is there exactly for this purpose, i.e. supporting integer values exceeding the capacity of `long`.

Comment: @Andreas, ah ok noted.

Comment: You could represent the result as a byte array, where each byte represent a (decimal) digit. To be able to convert a sequence of ones and zeros into a decimal number you would need just two operations on this data: double it (= add it to itself) and add 1 to it.

Comment: I can’t use BigInteger because it’s an assignment I got from university. So looking for creative solution here.

Comment: An array of bytes. You might want to search on "binary-coded decimal", often abbreviated as BCD. This was often used for this purpose in the old days of computing back when the dinosaurs like me did the programming.

Answer (score 0):

> How to represent a number that longer than long and print it

A full-blown number representation (like `BigInteger`) is not necessary for this.

If *all you want to do* is to print an `int[]` containing a zeros and ones as a binary number, then the simple way is just use a `String` to represent the number.

You could build it something like this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(array.length);
for (int i: array) {
    sb.append(i == 0 ? "0" : "1");
}
String binary = sb.toString();
```

Note that the above is more efficient than:

```
....
    binary += (i == 0 ? "0" : "1");
....
```

This can be done more concisely using Java 8+ streams.

---

> I want to print the decimal number presentation of the array.

If that *literally* what you want to do, then you actually do need at least a limited "big number" implementation.  (Sufficient to do repeated division by 10.)

However, I don't actually see the point of turning what is effectively an array of bits (zeros and ones) into a base-10 number.

---

> In order to do so, I need to convert each bit in a cell with the form 2^n (n is the cell number) and summarize all the powers.

I have no idea what you mean by "summarize the powers", but I suspect that it arises from you thinking that you *need* a decimal numeric representation.

Comment: Fair enough, but he writes that he want to print the **decimal number presentation**

Comment: Ah.  OK.  But lets see what the OP says.  (Because printing a decimal representation doesn't seem like a particularly useful thing to do.)  I'm inclined to think that OP has not expressed himself clearly and accurately ...

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use [`BitSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html), initialize the number of bits to the length of your array, iterate through the array to set the corresponding bit, and then get the resulting byte array with the `toByteArray()` method.  You could either parse the resulting byte array or feed it to the BigInteger constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to implement manual addition of arbitrary sized numbers.

In pseudo code:

implement manual addition function add(a, b)

create variables power2 = 1 and total = 0
loop from low bit to high bit over array

- if bit is set, total = add(total, power2)
- power2 = add(power2, power2)

return total